# How to remove X and Y labels from corrplot() MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
corrplot(T(:,1:4), 'type', 'Pearson');
```

Assigning a handle to corrplot only generates a 4x4 matrix of the corrolation of variables.

I attempted to do this.

```
fh = corrplot(T(:,1:4), 'type', 'Pearson');
th = findall(fh, 'type', 'text', 'String', '{\bf Correlation Matrix}'); 
th.String = '';
```

But it did not work, how do I remove the X and Y labels from this function.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach may be to first get all of the handles for the `Axes` objects created (since I believe `corrplot` creates multiple subplots):

```
hAxes = findall(gcf, 'Type', 'Axes');
```

Once you have handles to all the `Axes` objects, it should be easy to clear their x and y labels (and titles as well, if desired):

```
set([hAxes.XLabel], 'String', '');
set([hAxes.YLabel], 'String', '');
set([hAxes.Title], 'String', '');
```

Comment: @James: Which `corrplot` function are you using? Is it from a toolbox, the File Exchange, or elsewhere? What MATLAB version are you running your code in?

Comment: R2017a is the version im using, I wasnt aware of any other corrplot() however I copied the only use of it.

Comment: @James: That's the problem. There was no handle output available in R2017a. Try the other method I have above.